# How do I make this list function faster?

Tags: python, algorithm, list, optimization, dictionary

```
def removeDuplicatesFromList(seq): 
    # Not order preserving 
    keys = {}
    for e in seq:
        keys[e] = 1
    return keys.keys()

def countWordDistances(li):
    '''
    If li = ['that','sank','into','the','ocean']    
    This function would return: { that:1, sank:2, into:3, the:4, ocean:5 }
    However, if there is a duplicate term, take the average of their positions
    '''
    wordmap = {}
    unique_words = removeDuplicatesFromList(li)
    for w in unique_words:
        distances = [i+1 for i,x in enumerate(li) if x == w]
        wordmap[w] = float(sum(distances)) / float(len(distances)) #take average
    return wordmap
```

How do I make this function faster?

Answer (score 15):

```
import collections
def countWordDistances(li):
    wordmap = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for i, w in enumerate(li, 1):
        wordmap[w].append(i)
    for k, v in wordmap.iteritems():
        wordmap[k] = sum(v)/float(len(v))

    return wordmap
```

This makes only one pass through the list, and keeps operations to a minimum.  I timed this on a word list with 1.1M entries, 29k unique words, and it was almost twice as fast as Patrick's answer.  On a list of 10k words, 2k unique, it was more than 300x faster than the OP's code.

To make Python code go faster, there are two rules to keep in mind: use the best algorithm, and avoid Python.

On the algorithm front, iterating the list once instead of N+1 times (N= number of unique words) is the main thing that will speed this up.

On the "avoid Python" front, I mean: you want your code to be executing in C as much as possible.  So using `defaultdict` is better than a dict where you explicitly check if the key is present.  `defaultdict` does that check for you, but does it in C, in the Python implementation.  `enumerate` is better than `for i in range(len(li))`, again because it's fewer Python steps.   And `enumerate(li, 1)` makes the counting start at 1 instead of having to have a Python +1 somewhere in the loop.

Edited: Third rule: use PyPy.  My code goes twice as fast on PyPy as on 2.7.

Comment: +1 for cool optimizations. I had a decent idea of the best algorithm but didn't have the Python knowhow you clearly have.

Comment: Why not accumulate the sufficient statistics total and number instead?  I'll add an answer.

Comment: @Neil G: good job, yours is about 10% faster than mine, and suggests another rule: avoid memory allocations.

Comment: +1 for "avoid Python [by using Python smartly]" - from your tweet I was expecting "avoid Python" to be about native extensions or something.

Comment: "Use PyPy" and "Avoid python" don't come that well together. Preferably "use PyPy" and "use Python"?

Answer (score 5):

Based off @Ned Batchelder's solution, but without creating dummy lists:

```
import collections
def countWordDistances(li):
    wordmap = collections.defaultdict(lambda:[0.0, 0.0])
    for i, w in enumerate(li, 1):
        wordmap[w][0] += i
        wordmap[w][1] += 1.0
    for k, (t, n) in wordmap.iteritems():
        wordmap[k] = t / n
    return wordmap
```

Comment: OK, how's this for a gross hack: if you only need a list of two reals, then use a single complex number instead!  It cuts 25% off the running time of your solution, but yuck!

Comment: @Ned: Ha, yeah!  Did you try `lambda:numpy.zeros(2)`? You would know better than I, but one day, I'm hoping that someone writes a great Python optimizer so that we can focus on the algorithms (which is I why I fell in love with Python.)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this will be faster than using a set, but it requires only one pass through the list:

```
def countWordDistances(li):
    wordmap = {}
    for i in range(len(li)):
        if li[i] in wordmap:
            avg, num = wordmap[li[i]]
            new_avg = avg*(num/(num+1.0)) + (1.0/(num+1.0))*i
            wordmap[li[i]] = new_avg, num+1
        else:
            wordmap[li[i]] = (i, 1)

    return wordmap
```

This returns a modified version of wordmap, with the values associated with each key being a tuple of the average position and the number of occurences. You could obviously easily transform this to the form of the original output, but this would take some time.

The code basically keeps a running average while iterating through the list, recalculating each time by taking a weighted average.

Comment: Making only one pass through the list is key.

Answer (score 1):

Use a set:

```
def countWordDistances(li):
    '''
    If li = ['that','sank','into','the','ocean']    
    This function would return: { that:1, sank:2, into:3, the:4, ocean:5 }
    However, if there is a duplicate term, take the average of their positions
    '''
    wordmap = {}
    unique_words = set(li)
    for w in unique_words:
        distances = [i+1 for i,x in enumerate(li) if x == w]
        wordmap[w] = float(sum(distances)) / float(len(distances)) #take average
    return wordmap
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that springs to mind is to use a set to remove duplicate words:

```
unique_words = set(li)
```

In general, though, if you're worried about speed you need to profile the function to see where the bottleneck is, and then try to reduce that bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`frozenset`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) instead of a `dict`, since you're not doing anything with the values:

```
def removeDuplicatesFromList(seq):
    return frozenset(seq)
```

Comment: Everyone else recommends using set. What's the advantage of using frozenset?

Comment: @user849364: The main difference is that a `set` is mutable, whereas a `frozenset` is immutable.  There's no performance advantage, I believe, but it tells the readers of your code that the set is not going to be modfied.  See the Python docs for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension:

```
def countWordDistances(l):
    unique_words = set(l)
    idx = [[i for i,x in enumerate(l) if x==item]
            for item in unique_words]
    return {item:1.*sum(idx[i])/len(idx[i]) + 1.
            for i,item in enumerate(unique_words)}

li = ['that','sank','into','the','ocean']
countWordDistances(li)
# {'into': 3.0, 'ocean': 5.0, 'sank': 2.0, 'that': 1.0, 'the': 4.0}

li2 = ['that','sank','into','the','ocean', 'that']
countWordDistances(li2)
# {'into': 3.0, 'ocean': 5.0, 'sank': 2.0, 'that': 3.5, 'the': 4.0}
```

Answer (score -1):

Oneliner -

```
from __future__ import division   # no need for this if using py3k

def countWordDistances(li):
    '''
    If li = ['that','sank','into','the','ocean']    
    This function would return: { that:1, sank:2, into:3, the:4, ocean:5 }
    However, if there is a duplicate term, take the average of their positions
    '''
    return {w:sum(dist)/len(dist) for w,dist in zip(set(li), ([i+1 for i,x in enumerate(li) if x==w] for w in set(li))) }
```

What I am making in the last line is a dictionary comprehension, similar to a list comprehension.

Comment: Dictionary comprehensions are available in python 2.7, too. Before that, the same idea can be used by calling `dict` with a generator comprehension, e.g., `dict((i, 2*i) for i in range(4))' produces '{0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 6}'.

Comment: Does this work for you?  I get "global name 'w' is not defined" because the "x == w" is inside the loop that defines w.